# Set volume to mp3 stream using NAudio

Tags: c#-4.0, mp3, naudio, lame

Here in this code,
    I am using NAudio and Lame to convert wav file to mp3 stream and I am getting mp3 stream output without any issues. But apart from this I also want to set volume to the final mp3 stream. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 public byte[] ConvertWavToMP3(byte[] bt, uint bitrate)
 {         

     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bt);
     ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     var ws = new WaveFileReader(ms);

     byte[] wavdata = null;
     using (MemoryStream wavstrm = new MemoryStream())
     using (WaveFileWriter wavwri = new WaveFileWriter(wavstrm, ws.WaveFormat))
     {
        ws.CopyTo(wavwri);
        wavdata = wavstrm.ToArray();
     }

     WaveLib.WaveFormat fmt = new WaveLib.WaveFormat(ws.WaveFormat.SampleRate, ws.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample, ws.WaveFormat.Channels);

     Yeti.Lame.BE_CONFIG beconf = new Yeti.Lame.BE_CONFIG(fmt, bitrate);

     using (MemoryStream mp3strm = new MemoryStream())
     using (Mp3Writer mp3wri = new Mp3Writer(mp3strm, fmt, beconf))
     {               

        mp3wri.Write(wavdata, 0, wavdata.Length);
        byte[] mp3data = mp3strm.ToArray();
        return mp3data;
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AudioFileReader` which will give you a Volume property you can adjust (1.0 is full scale). It will also turn the audio into an `ISampleProvider` with IEEE float samples, but I think LAME accepts IEEE float, otherwise use `SampleToWaveProvider16` to get back down to 16 bit integer samples.

Comment: But @Mark AudioFileReader accepts only filename as parameter. You can see my above code where after converting to mp3 I need to set volume. Is it possible to set volume at that level?

Comment: AudioFileReader uses the SampleChannel class to convert IWaveProvider to ISampleProvider and add a VolumeProperty.

Comment: Hi @Mark i need to pass only stream but AudioFileReader has file name as parameter which is not my requirement.